# How to check if else conditions containing window.location.href (React Component) using Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm new into using files with .spec.js suffix to test files with Jest, so hope it's not a stupid question. I didn't found anything through Google + Stackoverflow research.

I would like to check an if else condition containing a new window.location using jest.

Here is my file.ts

```
export const loadBSection = (bSectionId: string) => async (
  dispatch: Dispatch,
  getState: GetState,
  { bSectionApi }: Deps,
) => {
  try {
    ...
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch(setBSectionErrorMessage(e.message));
    if (e.response.status === 404) {
      window.location.href = '/page-not-found.html';
    }
  }
};
```

My file.spec.ts

```
it('should .. and forward to a 404 page', async () => {
    ...
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([setBSectionLoading(true), setBSectionErrorMessage(errorMessage)]);

    // TODO what is expected here?
    
  });
```

Do you have any ideas?

As I'm new to this, maybe you have some sources for deep dives?

I used: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/ as an intro.
Do you have other resources which are helpful to find some documentation in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved!

So it was useful to set `response` optional so that other errors get catched as well. Furthermore it's easier to mock functions, so I changed `window.location.href` to `window.location.assign(url)`.
Makes the same but easier for testing.

**file.ts**

```
catch (e) {
    dispatch(setBSectionErrorMessage(e.message));
    if (e.response?.status === 404) {
      window.location.assign('/page-not-found.html');
    }
  }
```

**file.spec.ts**

I'm creating `error` and `errorMessage` inside of the test method. Here you can see how an error object can be assembled with a status code as a response:

```
it('should navigate to /page-not-found.html ...', async () => {
    const bSectionIdMock = '123';
    const error = Object.assign((new Error(), { response: { status: 404 } }));
    bSectionApi.bSectionsBSectionIdGet.mockRejectedValue(error);

    window.location.assign = jest.fn();

    await store.dispatch(loadBSection(bSectionIdMock));

    expect(window.location.assign).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/page-not-found.html');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea I had but not sure if it works

```
Object.defineProperty(window.location, 'href', {
  writable: true,
  value: '/page-not-found.html',
});
```

Comment: mmh.. tried it but doesn't work. Guess it's important to add that it's compulsory (if status 404)